What is common practice for naming C functions associated with structs?
I have seen it recommended that structs are given Pascal Case names:
struct MyStruct
{
    //...
};
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;

But what is considered good practice for functions associated with this struct me named? E.g.
MyStruct_print(MyStruct *my_struct);

or
my_struct_print(MyStruct *my_struct);

?

Use snake_case with the struct name as a prefix, e.g., my_struct_print().
This groups functions logically and avoids naming conflicts. Avoid PascalCase for function names in C.

"Avoid PascalCase for function names in C" - that is very much opinion based. E.g. MS seems to have a different opinion if you looks at Win32 API.

@wohlstad C is the product of the unix culture, and they were using snake case. Furthermore, Win32 API is ugly, and M/S opinion can be ignored.

@Moses beauty is in the eyes of the beholder. And definitely opinion based.

Note that my question isn't one about opinion. If both practices are common, then both practices are common regardless of what people think.
